# Storing the numeric return value of a SQL Server stored procedure into a variable results in said variable always being zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Simple stored procedure and simple invocation in SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SEQUENCES]
(
    [SEQ_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [SEQ_NEXT_ID] [numeric](11, 0) NOT NULL,
    [SEQ_INCREMENT] [numeric](2, 0) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [SEQ_PK] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SEQ_NAME] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]
    @SequenceName [NVARCHAR](MAX),
    @Increment [INT]
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[SEQUENCES]
    SET SEQ_NEXT_ID = SEQ_NEXT_ID + @Increment
    OUTPUT deleted.SEQ_NEXT_ID
    WHERE SEQ_NAME = @SequenceName
END

BEGIN
    DECLARE @value NUMERIC(11,0);

    EXEC @value = SomeStoredProcedure 'FOO', 1;  -- 'FOO' already exists in SEQUENCES so we do get a value

    -- weird results    this always prints 0     if we uncomment the return
    -- statement right below then and only then the correct value is printed
    PRINT @value;
    -- RETURN;

    INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (ID, NAME) 
    VALUES (@value, -- @value is always zero so we get a PK constraint violation ...
            'Something');
END
```

The value that `@value` gets is always zero and because of this we get an PK constraint violation on the update statement:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line ...
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SOME_TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (0).

If we uncomment the 'return' statement in the middle of the block then and only then the PRINT statement prints out the correct value. Must be missing something really obvious but what?

Comment: Do you have records in SOME_TABLE right now? What does the record look like in SEQUENCES for FOO right now?

Comment: For SEQ_NAME='FOO' the SEQUENCES table contains SEQ_NEXT_ID = 128. Everything is ok in that regard. The incrementation happens. It's just that we can't get the correct return value unless we uncomment the 'return' statement which is weird.

Comment: Have you heard of the sequence object? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 You should strongly consider moving that them instead of the approach here. You have created a race condition to get new values here. The sequence is a far more robust method of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Sean Lange you are absolutely right. It's just that I am dealing with a legacy DB and there's only so much I can do at this point on it.

Comment: Legacy? You said it is sql server 2014. Sequences are alive and well in 2014.

Comment: @Sean Lange it got ported over to 2014 but the people who wrote the original implementation (for whatever reasons) structured the entire db around their own SEQUENCE table you see here (this is what the term 'legacy' stands for in the given context). What you see here is a small fraction of a much larger picture. I can't refactor the entire DB with a more modern approach at a moment's notice.

Comment: You don't need to refactor the database. Change that stored procedure to use a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you you want to return some values from the stored procedure you need to use OUTPUT parameters.

For example create procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]
   @SequenceName [nvarchar](max),
   @Increment [int],
   @Value int OUTPUT
```

and then assign proper value to @Value parameter.

To read value returned from the stored procedure use:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure] 'FOO', 1, @Value = @Value OUTPUT;
```

Value 0 after `EXEC @value = SomeStoredProcedure 'FOO', 1;` means that stored procedure returned no errors.

Comment: To make this more complete, you should include details on how to OP should use `EXEC` when there is an `OUTPUT` parameter

Comment: Quick question: Would you be kind enough to also explain why the print statement prints the correct value if we simply un-comment the 'return' statement right below the print? I just can't wrap my head around this quirky behavior.

Comment: PRINT statement will not print correct value. But you may see value returned by "OUTPUT deleted.SEQ_NEXT_ID" in the query result pane, you will still see 0 in the messages pane.

Comment: If you use the syntax `EXEC @Variable = SP` then `@Variable` will be assigned the `RETURN` value **returned** by the SP (that is *not* the same as the value of the **dataset** returned by the SP). An SP, if it doesn't have a `RETURN` statement will return `0` on success; MS SP's will return the error code on failure. If you want to put the value of the dataset into a variable, you have to use a table variable, @XDS.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to do:
1. Add output param.

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProcedure]
       @SequenceName [nvarchar](max),
       @Increment [int],
       @NextId numeric(11, 0) OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN
         DECLARE  @nextIds TABLE (id NUMERIC(11, 0));

         UPDATE   [dbo].[SEQUENCES]
         SET      SEQ_NEXT_ID = SEQ_NEXT_ID + @Increment
         OUTPUT   DELETED.SEQ_NEXT_ID INTO @nextIds
         WHERE    SEQ_NAME    = @SequenceName;

         SET @NextId = (SELECT id FROM @nextIds);
   END
```

2. Get the output value from stored procedure.

   ```
   BEGIN
     DECLARE   @value           NUMERIC(11,0);

     EXECUTE SomeStoredProcedure 'FOO', 1, @value OUTPUT;  -- 'FOO' already exists in SEQUENCES so we do get a value

     -- weird results    this always prints 0     if we uncomment the return
     -- statement right below then and only then the correct value is printed
     --select @value;
     -- RETURN;

     INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE (ID,NAME) 
     VALUES ( @value, -- @value is always zero so we get a PK constraint violation ...
     'Something');
   END
   ```

Comment: Quick question: Would you be kind enough to also explain why the print statement prints the correct value if we simply un-comment the 'return' statement right below the print? I just can't wrap my head around this quirky behavior.

Comment: @XDS print statement is doing nothing, that value you see is the output from that stored procedure. If you want to see the print statement value you need to click on the message tab, look at that tab then you can see the print value. You can find message tab on the right of Result tab. "-- OUTPUT   deleted.SEQ_NEXT_ID" this is the value that you are looking as Print.

Answer (score 0):

Your proc is not returning anything.  There is no OUTPUT parameter that I can see.  Worse yet, you're calling code is assuming that the proc will return a string.  Procs return integers (return codes).